# Dealing with complicated JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an object like this:

```
var obj = {
    "00a9": ["\u00A9", ["copyright"]],
    "00ae": ["\u00AE", ["registered"]],
    "203c": ["\u203C", ["bangbang"]],
    "2049": ["\u2049", ["interrobang"]]
}
```

I would like make a simple object with this like

```
var obj = {
"\u00A9":"copyright",
"\u00AE":"registered"
}
```

so that I can easily get key and value without using that complicated object.

Purpose : I want to get copyright if I've key like \u00A9 or get \ua00A9 if I've value like copyright.

So what I tried now is to make 2 objects:

```
$(obj).each(function(key,val){
    unicodeToImg[val[0]] = val[1][0];
    imgToUnicode[val[1][0]] = val[0];
});
```

but this will return only key 0 and all values in it and when I try below code:

```
$(obj).each(function(key,val){
    $(val).each(function(k,v){
        console.log(k);
        console.log(v);
    });
    //unicodeToImg[val[0]] = val[1][0];
    //imgToUnicode[val[1][0]] = val[0];
});
```

it returns same

Comment: \ is not allowed in key value

Comment: Needs more explanation on how do you want your resulting output? What logic you are using to create it?

Comment: ok is there any other way to deal with these kind of object ?
I can't remove \ because in some values its like \uD83C\uDDE8\uD83C\uDDF3 4 slashes in between

Comment: Could it be that you iterate over the object itself and not it's keys? maybe try out Object.keys(obj).each()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Object.values` to get the object values (discarding the initial keys), and then turn the oddly formatted inner nested array into an easily-accessible object with `reduce`:

```js
var obj = {
    "00a9": ["\u00A9", ["copyright"]],
    "00ae": ["\u00AE", ["registered"]],
    "203c": ["\u203C", ["bangbang"]],
    "2049": ["\u2049", ["interrobang"]]
}
const transformedObj = Object.values(obj)
  .reduce((accum, [key, [val]]) => {
    accum[key] = val;
    return accum;
  }, {});
console.log(transformedObj);
console.log(transformedObj['\u00A9']);
```

No need for jQuery to achieve this

Comment: thanks buddy its working I can accept answer in 5 mins. that's what stackoverflow says I'll accept it in just 5 mins :)

Comment: @BillGates why to use `reduce` when you can simply get the object using a simple loop

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal `.reduce` is the appropriate method to use when you want to take in an array and produce an object. Your `forEach` method requires explicit mutation (as well as unnecessary access of the original object's `key`)

Comment: @CertainPerformance when you can achieve the same output with more sensible and self explanatory code using a `forEach` loop then I don't think `reduce` is necessary. And the thing you are saying is a convention and not a strict rule we follow. That was just my view mate.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal The array methods are there to be used - don't avoid them just because you don't know them, that's silly - figure them out and, when appropriate, use them!

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am not opposing your answer but why was my answer down voted?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I'm not the one who downvoted your answer, but if I had to guess, it's because someone else thought `forEach` over the keys is not the appropriate method to use here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.values` and `reduce` to form your two lookups in one go.

```js
var obj = {
    "00a9": ["\u00A9", ["copyright"]],
    "00ae": ["\u00AE", ["registered"]],
    "203c": ["\u203C", ["bangbang"]],
    "2049": ["\u2049", ["interrobang"]]
}

var result = Object.values(obj).reduce(function(acc,c){
    acc.unicodeToImg[c[0]] = c[1][0];
    acc.imgToUnicode[c[1][0]] = c[0];
    return acc;
},{unicodeToImg:{},imgToUnicode:{}});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = {
  '00a9': ['\u00A9', ['copyright']],
  '00ae': ['\u00AE', ['registered']],
  '203c': ['\u203C', ['bangbang']],
  2049: ['\u2049', ['interrobang']],
};

let finalObj = {};
const transform = (obj) => {
  for (let key in obj) {
    finalObj[obj[key][0]] = obj[key][1][0];
  }
};
transform(obj);

console.log(finalObj);
console.log(finalObj['\u00A9']);
```